# Convesion from Hive to PigLatin

Tags: hive, apache-pig

I am trying to convert the below Hive statement to Pig:

```
max(substr(case when url like 'http:%' then '' else url end,1,50))
```

My pig statement for the above is:

```
url_group = GROUP data by (uid);
max_substr_url= FOREACH url_group generate SUBSTRING(MAX(((Coalesce(data.url) matches '.*http:%.*') ? '' : Coalesce(data.url))), 0, 49);
```

For some of the data, the url can be null. So I have written a pig UDF called Coalesce(String) which returns an empty string if the data is either null or empty. If the data is not null or not empty it returns the string back.

The above pig statement is giving me lot of trouble and tried n different options/ways but nothing worked. Anyone got any ideas on how to implement this? Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "lot of trouble", "nothing worked" - be more specific

Comment: Pig uses java regexes for `matches`, so `%` is not needed in `.*http:%.*`. Also, why have you swapped MAX and substring in pig? It should be `MAX(SUBSTRING...`

Comment: Well, I tried many ways to get my Pig statement working but had no luck yet..

Comment: When I tried Max(Substring...) I was getting an error...and so I switched them. I am looking for advice/changes that I need to make to my logic to make it working. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to use a [nested `FOREACH`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#nestedblock) so that you can do the substring transformation on each tuple in the `data` bag then take the `MAX` of the transformed bag.

```
A = GROUP data by (uid);
B = FOREACH url_group {
    -- MAX needs a one column bag
    transformed = FOREACH data 
                  GENERATE SUBSTRING((Coalesce(url) matches '.*http:.*' ? '' : Coalesce(url)), 0, 49);
    GENERATE group AS uid, MAX(transformed) ;
}
```